# How can I open another url from a php file and pass some values with the get method?

Tags: php, get

I have a php script that checks if the user typed the right password for the right username.

If its right I want to open another php page and pass some values with the get method. How do I do this? Im pretty new to php.

Comment: I think is not good idea to pass login information with the `GET`methode

Comment: IM not going to send the password

Comment: I suggest you use $_SESSION for username.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to that page if this is your case:

```
if(condition){
 header("Location: yourfile.php?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2");
 exit();
}
```

Note: header should be called before any output, its recommended to call it at top of the page before printing anything.

Or use cURL to send the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `GET` to send password!

Instead try to use `cURL` lib and send it via `POST`.

Comment: Im not going to pass the password just the username. The login is not on the page I want to pass to.